# Reloading iron-ajax when a page is routed to

Tags: ajax, authentication, polymer

Looking for a suggestion for my problem.  I have a page that is routed to after the user has logged in.  This page is fetching some data with `iron-ajax` from the backend in the `attached` event handler.  My problem is when the user logins again after a logout, the page is routed to, but my `iron-ajax` is not reloaded - it seems that `attached` event is not being triggered anymore after the first time it was triggered.  Could anyone please help?  Looking for some sample code, as I am a newbie and the sample code will help me greatly in understanding the solution.  Thanks!

**Updated with sample code.**  The (simplified) code below is the page web component where the user is routed to after login.  `iron-ajax` is fired manually in the `attached` event handler.  However, the next time the user logins again after a logout (without closing the browser), the `attached` event handler is not being called.

```
<dom-module id="device-section">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
        :host {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>

    <app-config id="config"></app-config>
    <iron-localstorage name="session" value="{{session}}"></iron-localstorage>
    <app-data key="session" data="{{session}}"></app-data>

    <iron-ajax
        id="getDevices"
        url="{{url}}"
        method="get"
        handle-as="json"
        last-response="{{devices}}"></iron-ajax>

    <div class="card">
        <h1>Devices</h1>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{devices.result}}">
            <div class="card">
                <p class="heading">Device</p>
                <p>[[item.devicePrint.name]] [[item.devicePrint.userAgent]]</p>
                <p class="heading">Registered</p>
                <p>[[item.lastSelectedDate]]</p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'device-section',
      properties: {
        session: Object
      },

      attached: function() {
         this.$.getDevices.url
                = this.$.config.server.url.base
                  + this.$.config.server.url.getDevicesPath.replace("{userName}", this.session.userName);
            this.$.getDevices.generateRequest();
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example? You will most likely need to manually call the `generateRequest` on the `iron-ajax` element or change a dummy parameter on it.

Comment: @alesc, question updated with sample code.  The problem I'm having is I don't know how to trigger the second `generateRequest` after the first it's fired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are dealing here is the following. When you are using `iron-pages` for displaying one page at a time (regarding the current route), all of the pages are instantiated only once at the beginning.

In your case, you will need to somehow to communicate with that particular page that it is currently in view, so that you can fire your AJAX request every time the page is displayed.

In order to do so, modify your custom component in the following way:

```
<dom-module id="device-section">
    <template>
        Device section page

        <iron-ajax
            id="getDevices"
            url="manifest.json"
            method="get"
            handle-as="json"
            last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'device-section',
            properties: {
                active: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    value: false,
                    observer: '_activeChanged',
                },
            },

            attached: function() { 
                console.log('setting URL');
                // Here you would set your URL
            },

            _activeChanged: function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if(newValue) {
                    console.log('firing request');
                    this.$.getDevices.generateRequest();
                }
            },
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

As you can see, I have removed all of the non-essential code. The important parts are:
test

1. Setting the URL in the `attached` callback, as you have already done. But don't fire the request here, because we will fire it later when the page comes into view. In my opinion, you should also use the `created` callback instead of the `attached`.
2. Define a new property Boolean `active`, which defaults to `false` and has an observer method.
3. In the observer method for the `active` property, you fire the AJAX request when the `newValue` equals `true`. This means that the page has currently come into view. Will talk about setting the `active` property a bit later.

So, this was the component part. Now comes the part where I show you how to modify the use of your component. Again, I have provided you with a bare minimum example with the following code:

```
<template is="dom-bind">
    <input type="number" value="{{selectedPage::input}}" />

    <iron-pages selected="[[selectedPage]]" selected-attribute="active">
        <section>First page</section>
        <device-section></device-section>
        <section>Third page</section>
    </iron-pages>
</template>
```

The only important part here is the `selected-attribute="active"` attribute on the `iron-pages`. This does the following: it simply adds the `active` property to whichever page is currently selected. In my case, only the `device-section` element will actually read this property, since other pages don't define it nor need it - they will simply ignore the property.

This means that when the `device-section` page comes into view, its' `active` property will be set and the property observer will fire the AJAX request. You can see that the AJAX request will always be fired when you switch between the pages.

There is also a side-effect. In your sample code, the AJAX request always fired at the beginning (at page load), even if you never navigated to that page. Now, this happens lazily at that particular page view.

Hope this meets your requirements and solves your problem. If you have any comments, don't hesitate to write them and I will do my best to address them.